# What does it mean when someone says store event itself but not the state/data?

Tags: event-sourcing

What does it mean when someone says store event itself in the journal but not the state/data? such that one can replay the events to build the state. Can someone explain how the data in journal look like since there is no storing of state? Does one store the functions itself?

Comment: There are many resources that come in Google search when you look for event sourcing, including excellent videos. I recommend reading this http://docs.geteventstore.com/introduction/4.0.0/event-sourcing-basics/ and watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHGkaShoyNs. Since these are links, this does not qualify as answer but you can lean a lot by following these links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you persist only what has changed in the state and not all the state. I will give you and example.

Let's suppose that you have an `InventoryAggregate` that stores items, like `Products`. Internally, this `Aggregate` stores a list of all items but when a command to add the item X arrives (`AddItemXCommand`) it produces the event that item x was added (`ItemXWasAddedEvent`). Next time a similar command arrives, the `Aggregate Repository` loads from the `Event Store` (from the *Journal* if you want) all the previous generated events and apply them one-by-one onto the Aggregate in order to build the state (in this particular example, to build the list of all added items).

So, after the command arrives and is executed, the `state` changes (an item is added to the list) but you don't persist it (you don't persist the item list), you persist only the generated event (that an item was added). After you persist that event you can discard the `Aggregate` and its internal `state`.

As an optimization, you can persist the internal state, so when a command arrives, you don't have to load+apply all the events, only the events that were generated after the state was cached. This state at a particular moment is know as `Snapshot`.

Comment: Hi! This is a good explanation but can you give a concrete example. I am getting confused on how data would look like in the Journal. Say you are adding products to inventory so can you tell me how the data would like in the journal?

Comment: { eventType: "ProductWaAdded", productId: "1234", productName: "Wireless keyboard", price: 456 }

Comment: This example is JSON. The actual representation depends on the persistence mechanism.

Comment: I see. So say if the price changed to 500 then the next row in the journal would like this ? { eventType: "PriceChanged", productId: "1234", price: 500 }. As one can see I am only storing the updated column price. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You don't store the entire Product.

Comment: This also means we don't just persist the event but also the change in state right? Because the third paragraph in your answer says "you don't persist the item list but you only persist the generated event" but shouldn't this be you don't persist the item list but you persist the event plus the changes in the state of item list right?

Comment: The event should contain all the information needed to reconstruct the new state.

Comment: The event name/type dictates *what* changed and the event body tells *how* it changed

Comment: Got it! Finally, to know what has changed from previous state every subsequent event request should know the state of previous one right?

Comment: The aggregate knows all it needs to know as it reads all previous events. Given a command and all previous events an Aggregate has all information to generate a new event with what has changed. This new event will be used by it the next time it receives a new command.

Comment: Does it cache the previous state all the time because going to journal to read all the previous events to insert a new event sounds expensive (other words read before write from the journal sounds very expensive but if it is from cache then there is no problem) ?

Comment: It could store a snapshot for the state but only if it is realy realy needed. **In general snapshoting is not required.** I don't use it for example. I don't need it and if I will it will be added as a plugin and the application will not even know or care.

Comment: However,  please note that the `Aggregate` does not loads itself from `Event store`. It is the responsability of the `Aggregate Repository` to do this. So if you need the snapshoting then you will implement it there. The `Aggregate` will not know that it is loaded from cache.